# How can I sync time between 3 computer through a LAN on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sync, time

How can I synchronize time between 3 computers in a LAN?

1) One of these 3 computers is used as a server on which I have a network drive. This computer uses Internet time based on the Ethernet card (Internet on the Ethernet card and connected to the LAN on the wireless card).

2) The other two computers are connected to the LAN on their wireless card via a router.

What I did was: I synchronized the time on computer 1 (server) to get the Internet time.

I put the IP (LAN) address of the server (computer 1) on the other computer in their Internet time section, but it doesn't work. He says peer unreachable, hence each computer pings one another successfully.

Do you have any idea ?

**ALL 3 computers are running Windows 10 Home Edition**

Comment: You either run a local NTP server (Windows Server can do that in AD), or point them all to the same external time server.

Comment: How can I put the 2 other computers (Comp 2 & 3) in the LAN to the external server?

Comment: If they have no internet access at all, you'll just have to set up your own local NTP server. If they do have internet access, then just point them there or leave the default.

Comment: The server is using internet time, but I'd like to make the other PCs use the server time, but I can't on windows 10. In the internet time section, when I pass the IP address of the server, it gives an error.

Comment: Again, either you install NTP server software (because time sync is the very specific NTP protocol and requires server software, not just the IP address of any random machine) or you just sync them all against the same external server. What is not clear is why you cannot simply use the same external server: it's easier and is sub-ms precise already since NTP compensates for network latency. There's almost never a reason to run your own in such a small environment.

Comment: Thank you for your response Bob, I'll try with NTP server.

I have internet only on the ethernet side, not on the wireless side; that's why I had to proceed that way.

Comment: In that case you're probably looking for a [third party NTP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/178802/looking-for-a-ntp-server-software-for-windows/399140).